# How do you do an exhaustive switch case in Typescript with string enums that refer to other string enums

Tags: typescript

I have a string enum that is a subset of the values from another string enum. I am trying to do an exhaustive switch case across the former.

This is a contrived example of the construct I am attempting to represent in Typescript

```
const enum Color {
    BLUE = 'Blue',
    YELLOW = 'Yellow',
    RED = 'Red'
}

const enum SupportedColor {
    BLUE = Color.BLUE,
    YELLOW = Color.YELLOW
}


function doSomething(colorFromOutsideInput: string): boolean {
    const supportedColor: SupportedColor = (colorFromOutsideInput as unknown) as SupportedColor;
    switch (supportedColor) {
        case SupportedColor.BLUE:
            return true;
        case SupportedColor.YELLOW:
            return true;
        default:
            return invalidColor(supportedColor);
    }
}

function invalidColor(supportedColor: never): never {
    throw new Error();
}
```

In this code, the default in the switch case fails compilation with

```
Argument of type 'SupportedColor' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

If I were to do this switch case across the `Color` enum instead of `SupportedColor` enum, it would work.

Based on reading in the typescript docs, I see no evidence of why the compiler treats the two enums differently because they evaluate to the same strings.

Comment: Why `supportedColor` is defined as `never` in `function invalidColor(supportedColor: never)`? And what's the purpose of `const supportedColor: SupportedColor = (colorFromOutsideInput as unknown) as SupportedColor;` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to minimize the example a bit but the issues raised are the same.

---

Enums where each enum value is of an explicit [string literal](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) or [numeric literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types) type act like [union types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), which can be narrowed via [type guards](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).  This sort of enum is called a [union enum](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#union-enums-and-enum-member-types):

```
// union enum
const enum SupportedColor {
    BLUE = "Blue",
    YELLOW = "Yellow"
}

// no error here
function doSomething(supportedColor: SupportedColor): boolean {
    switch (supportedColor) {
        case SupportedColor.BLUE:
            supportedColor // SupportedColor.BLUE
            return true;
        case SupportedColor.YELLOW:
            supportedColor // SupportedColor.YELLOW
            return true;
    }
    //supportedColor // never
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- unreachable code
}
```

In the above code, the compiler recognizes that the `switch` statement is exhaustive because `supportedColor` of type `SupportedColor` can be narrowed by control flow anlaysis.  The type `SupportedColor` is equivalent to the union `SupportedColor.BLUE | SupportedColor.YELLOW`.

So inside the various `case`s, `supportedColor` is narrowed in turn to the type `SupportedColor.BLUE` and `SupportedColor.YELLOW`.  After the `switch` statement is over, the compiler knows that `supportedColor` is of type `never`, since both `SupportedColor.BLUE` and `SupportedColor.YELLOW` have been filtered out of the union.  If you uncomment the code after the `switch` block, the compiler will even complain that it is unreachable in TS3.7+.

Therefore all code paths return a value and the compiler does not complain.

---

Now consider what happens when you change the enum values to be calculated instead of literals:

```
const enum Color {
    BLUE = 'Blue',
    YELLOW = 'Yellow',
    RED = 'Red'
}

// calculated enum
const enum SupportedColor {
    BLUE = Color.BLUE,
    YELLOW = Color.YELLOW
}

function doSomething(supportedColor: SupportedColor): boolean { // error!
    // -------------------------------------------->  ~~~~~~~
    // function lacks ending return statement
    switch (supportedColor) {
        case SupportedColor.BLUE:
            supportedColor // SupportedColor
            return true;
        case SupportedColor.YELLOW:
            supportedColor // SupportedColor
            return true;
    }
    supportedColor // SupportedColor
}
```

Here the enum type `SupportedColor` is no longer considered to be a union type.  *Calculated enums are not union enums*.  And therefore the compiler has no way to narrow or filter the type of `supportedColor` in or after the `switch` statement.  The type stays `SupportedColor` the whole way through.  And the `switch` statement isn't seen to be exhaustive, and the compiler complains that the function doesn't always return a value.

---

So that explains what's going on, and the documentation link for union enums does say that union enums and calculated enums are different.  So it's documented.  But what isn't explained in the documentation is *why* calculated enums are not treated as unions.  That is: it's working as designed, but does anyone actually prefer it to be this way, or is it just a design limitation?

The closest thing I can find to a canonical answer is the GitHub issue [microsoft/TypeScript#22709](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22709) referencing some meeting notes inside [microsoft/TypeScript#26241](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26241).  These notes are:

> - There are actually many kinds of enums under the hood
> - Union enums only get created when only bare literals (or nothing) are initializers
> - These kinds of enums behave differently
> - You might want one or the other and this is how you choose
> - Working As Intended; would be a Breaking Change

So the TS team says that non-union enums are actually sometimes desirable and that making a change here would break existing code which relies on the current behavior.  It's not particularly satisfying of an answer since it doesn't describe the use cases in which people want non-union enums, but it's an answer nonetheless: this is intentional.  If you want union enums, use literals and not calculated values.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBVYBLA9sAosArmEgN4CwAUElUgPQ1L4bZIQFgXVLzZQAuLbJAGV8MGJgBOvCABMAwpgA2kkh07UAQgBkUOJAF4kAIg2L8EIwBo16pAE0cWrQHkA6geN2Ii5QHcjNkgAvhSBdEjAmCwSEioAFhASEIEAZozwvFjASDKYQpiQvHHowADmABRQouJSsgrKEgBcwtWS0vJKkgCUzQBGmEoQINlklLZIUL7ovPBxSJWttR0NXapj49TwIFDIImJtdZ0SAHTauo2BG5xV+0v1KuF7Ne33J2c4l1dUSbz4Etm8CTmADcn1sWx2LVuLyOxwcTjcF3WX2oN2ehwatHoTwOy0kcMcLlcYKuPz+AKBEFByM4IRp1DoaNxryxEQgADdEiS6AA-Pn8gX8pAAHgAtKKGMAkgg4iBeopkNwZMlkXS6RRQJBYAhkHIQIp4PhFCB2nhCGtONxgHwBOaWaMNu8PAByUzmZ3WelUeFEl1eHyYXwekkAJRwABEXSHZM7AurkeEtgajSbZLb2MirTbWOacXcjhbxk7DK9TjocJ6Nj63B5S9XiarQsi0sAMlkcnkChAiiUKkz8w1mnmYSs+gMFcMSKzErEJABCbn0cXLlertfrjebgB8VEFfMXSBbbeYxvgAGsoAIZL2kGT-hNeKnIMBeCTJtNZvN+yPuoWvhDdkWH83nLJEUXUb8MQebEgKgiQSQ2O8KRBBDNm2QDoTggkEVcMDwNRWC8QkVlhzg1DbCQpBARQr1gjfQiWUeBijjjCh4yAA)

Comment: As an aside: I have recently used a construct like the following to define a subset **type** of an enum: `type SupportedColor = Extract<Color, Color.BLUE | Color.YELLOW>`. Then one can *optionally* also define a **constant object** to access the constants: `const SupportedColor: Record<SupportedColor, Color> = { [Color.BLUE]: Color.BLUE, [Color.YELLOW]: Color.YELLOW }`. The latter starts to get hacky, but it is useful e.g. when iterating the constants - at least everything is defined separate from where it is used in code; a single `enum` definition or similar would have been more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the intention of the example, but consider changing the signature of `invalidColor` to receive type `unknown`:

```
function invalidColor(supportedColor: unknown): never {
    throw new Error();
}
```